# XML Schema, how to put "conditions" into restrictions?

Tags: xml, if-statement, schema

I've a XML Schema and I would like to know if it's possible to put conditions in.
I would like to choice minInclusive and maxInclusive for each month.It's possible to do that in the xml schema. I  would appreciate any help. =)

Here's my code:

```
<xs:element name="correo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="emisor">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="apellidos" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="receptor">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="apellidos" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>


            <xs:element name="fecha">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="dia">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="31"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="mes">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Enero"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Febrero"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Marzo"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Abril"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Mayo"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Junio"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Julio"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Agosto"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Septiembre"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Octubre"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Noviembre"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Diciembre"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="año">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="hora">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="horas">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                                <xs:maxInclusive value="23"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="minutos">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                                <xs:maxInclusive value="59"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="adjuntos">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="archivo">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="extension" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="tamaño">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>  
                                                <xs:element name="valor">
                                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                                                            <xs:minInclusive value="0."/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="unidades" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>   

            <xs:element name="mensaje">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="cuerpo" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="firma" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>                   

        </xs:sequence>  
        <xs:attribute name="asunto" type="xs:string"/>    
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing with assertions in XSD 1.1. It can't be done in XSD 1.0.